# Can a TextView inside LinearLayout container be collapsed and expand on Button click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I can dynamically add the text fields in my `LinearLayout` container.

Now I need to collapse those added fields in click of the `Button` those added fields should get collapse with any label.

Can it be done? Below is the code that i can add the `EditText` dynamically.

[image]

```
txtHeading = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
     LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_icon_select);
     TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);

     textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
     textIn.setText(null);

     Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
     buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
          }
     });

    container.addView(addView);
}}});

    btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //What to insert here?
```

on click to save button in need to collapse all the textView Elements.

let us consider Heading is the label and it is named as Gender so if i added the options as male and female then after clicking the save button this should get collapsed under the Heading.

Comment: `View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` is best option to do that.

Comment: although this also the option.but i need to pass this collapsed items with its label into next activity.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "pass this collapsed items with its label into next activity"?

Comment: I need to pass this ITEMS into listview into next activity with the parent as the label and its options as child..

Comment: What is this ITEMS ?

Comment: Do you need only the text content of the removed textview items to pass on?

Comment: Label means text only I guess!?

Comment: For example: label of my edit text is Gender and i added the options as male and female. Now on click of save button i need to collapse the male and female text view under Gender.

Comment: If I am right, you can anyway get it by storing them as `String` value & passing with `Intent`.

Comment: Lable is the name for text field. It can be any thing like Descriptions,or Name or age anything

Comment: But now i just need to Collapse the male and female options under the gender Field.

Comment: Do one thing, reframe your question It is so damn confusing. & please add app screenshot if possible.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: On save button store currentData & then collapse with the use of `setVisibility() method.

Comment: try invalidate method on your layout after remove view

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I'm kind of guessing that you want... I would create a custom view class based on a linear layout.  Each having two edit texts.

Create and add this class to dynamically when the add button is pressed.  When the save button is pressed, you can loop over the parent LinearLayout's children and then call a helper method to collapse the second edit text element.

To Loop over the parent and collapse children.  Now the CustomElement and the collapseOptionField() call is custom code you must write.

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = findViewById(...);
for ( int i = 0; i < parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
   CustomElement ce = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
   ce.collapseOption();
}
```

**Update**

Custom class with collapse-able option:

```
public class TextWithOption extends LinearLayout {

   EditText edit0;
   EditText edit1;

   public TextWithOption(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context);
   }

   public TextWithOption(Context context) {
      super(context);

      View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.edit_text_option, null);

      edit0 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text0);
      edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);

      addView(view);
   }

   public void collapseOption() {
      edit1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }

   public void showOption() {
      edit1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Activity code that will add new options and then collapse them:

```
final LinearLayout optionsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.outer_layout);

 Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
 addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            TextWithOption to = new TextWithOption(context);
            optionsLayout.addView(to);
         }
      });

      ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < optionsLayout.getChildCount(); i++ ) {
               ((TextWithOption)optionsLayout.getChildAt(i)).collapseOption();
            }
         }
      });
```

Comment: can you please explain more or add more line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void collapse(final View v) {
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 1, 0);
    v.startAnimation(anim);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
}
```

onclick of button write view.collapse
view equals to whatever view you want collapse